# Dumb Question: Delta-Neutral fractional shares

Tags: delta-hedging

If neutralizing delta requires an addition of a fractional number of shares, e.g. 444.12345 do we  generally keep the decimals or round up to the nearest integer? I reckon rounding would no longer make it "neutral"?

Comment: Yes, we round. And yes, that introduces an error. But it is a small error, especially in a large position, as a big bank might have.

Comment: Great, thank you.

Comment: Years ago we would round (up or down) not just to a whole share, but to a [round lot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round_lot), which for almost all stocks was 100 shares. But as @noob2 wrote, for large positions this rounding did not make any material difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer: Round in practice. The error is relative small.